# How to find audio loop data in Unity files?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to extract audio assets from a Unity game. I can extract the .wav files with AssetStudio, but what I can't figure out is how to find the loop data. When I play the audio in AssetStudio's built-in audio player, the audio loops correctly, but I can't find the loop point in either the exported .wav files or the raw dump for the AudioClip files.